# WPILIB (FRC) Gradlew Issue (Gradle builds fine but gradlew doesn't)

Tags: java, gradle, robotics, wpilib

I recently installed wpilib on my windows laptop and start an project, but when I try to build the project using `gradlew` it doesnt work:

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "edu.wpi.first.GradleRIO" version "2024.1.1"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

def ROBOT_MAIN_CLASS = "frc.robot.Main"

// Define my targets (RoboRIO) and artifacts (deployable files)
// This is added by GradleRIO's backing project DeployUtils.
deploy {
    targets {
        roborio(getTargetTypeClass('RoboRIO')) {
            // Team number is loaded either from the .wpilib/wpilib_preferences.json
            // or from command line. If not found an exception will be thrown.
            // You can use getTeamOrDefault(team) instead of getTeamNumber if you
            // want to store a team number in this file.
            team = project.frc.getTeamNumber()
            debug = project.frc.getDebugOrDefault(false)

            artifacts {
                // First part is artifact name, 2nd is artifact type
                // getTargetTypeClass is a shortcut to get the class type using a string

                frcJava(getArtifactTypeClass('FRCJavaArtifact')) {
                }

                // Static files artifact
                frcStaticFileDeploy(getArtifactTypeClass('FileTreeArtifact')) {
                    files = project.fileTree('src/main/deploy')
                    directory = '/home/lvuser/deploy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def deployArtifact = deploy.targets.roborio.artifacts.frcJava

// Set to true to use debug for JNI.
wpi.java.debugJni = false

// Set this to true to enable desktop support.
def includeDesktopSupport = false

// Defining my dependencies. In this case, WPILib (+ friends), and vendor libraries.
// Also defines JUnit 5.
dependencies {
    implementation wpi.java.deps.wpilib()
    implementation wpi.java.vendor.java()

    roborioDebug wpi.java.deps.wpilibJniDebug(wpi.platforms.roborio)
    roborioDebug wpi.java.vendor.jniDebug(wpi.platforms.roborio)

    roborioRelease wpi.java.deps.wpilibJniRelease(wpi.platforms.roborio)
    roborioRelease wpi.java.vendor.jniRelease(wpi.platforms.roborio)

    nativeDebug wpi.java.deps.wpilibJniDebug(wpi.platforms.desktop)
    nativeDebug wpi.java.vendor.jniDebug(wpi.platforms.desktop)
    simulationDebug wpi.sim.enableDebug()

    nativeRelease wpi.java.deps.wpilibJniRelease(wpi.platforms.desktop)
    nativeRelease wpi.java.vendor.jniRelease(wpi.platforms.desktop)
    simulationRelease wpi.sim.enableRelease()

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty 'junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled', 'true'
}

// Simulation configuration (e.g. environment variables).
wpi.sim.addGui().defaultEnabled = true
wpi.sim.addDriverstation()

// Setting up my Jar File. In this case, adding all libraries into the main jar ('fat jar')
// in order to make them all available at runtime. Also adding the manifest so WPILib
// knows where to look for our Robot Class.
jar {
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    manifest edu.wpi.first.gradlerio.GradleRIOPlugin.javaManifest(ROBOT_MAIN_CLASS)
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

// Configure jar and deploy tasks
deployArtifact.jarTask = jar
wpi.java.configureExecutableTasks(jar)
wpi.java.configureTestTasks(test)

// Configure string concat to always inline compile
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs.add '-XDstringConcat=inline'
}
```

Now if I build with gradle, it builds perfectly fine

settings.gradle:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        String frcYear = '2024'
        File frcHome
        if (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) {
            String publicFolder = System.getenv('PUBLIC')
            if (publicFolder == null) {
                publicFolder = "C:\\Users\\Public"
            }
            def homeRoot = new File(publicFolder, "wpilib")
            frcHome = new File(homeRoot, frcYear)
        } else {
            def userFolder = System.getProperty("user.home")
            def homeRoot = new File(userFolder, "wpilib")
            frcHome = new File(homeRoot, frcYear)
        }
        def frcHomeMaven = new File(frcHome, 'maven')
        maven {
            name 'frcHome'
            url frcHomeMaven
        }
    }
}

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("org.gradle.internal.native.headers.unresolved.dependencies.ignore", "true");
```

I expected that it would build with gradlew as well but it doesnt,

heres my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=permwrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=permwrapper/dists
```

instead of building it gives me this:

```
>gradlew
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(SourceFile:70)
```

I have even tried regenerating the wrapper, `gradle wrapper`

**ALSO: FOR SOME REASON `gradlew` doesnt listen to commands its only building no matter what**

**EDIT:**
I have tried my code on github codespaces and my own linux (arch linux) but windows isn't working for me, i have reinstalled wpilib multiple times not sure why its doing this to me. I have tried using a vm of windows and it works it weird why my computer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this error was that you had to remove `.gradle` folder in your home directory `C:\Users\{username}\`. Now something must happened during my installation that caused this error to happen. Everything builds correctly now.

NOTE: You have to reboot your computer before removing it because it won't let you remove unless you reboot.